# I have checkbox, imageview and textview in android, I want to check my checkbox when i click the associated textview

Tags: android, checkbox

Here is my code.

```
    if (view == null) {         
        view = lInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.list_item_multiple_choice, null);
        vHolderMultiple = new ViewHolder();
        vHolderMultiple.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMultipleChoiceListItem);
        vHolderMultiple.cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbMultipleListItem);
        vHolderMultiple.iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivMultiChoiceItem);
        view.setTag(vHolderMultiple);
    } 
    else {
        vHolderMultiple = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    vHolderMultiple.tv.setText(optionArray.get(position).getOptionText());
    vHolderMultiple.cb.setChecked(lvAnswers.isItemChecked(position));
    if (optionArrayCopy.get(position).getImageUrl() != null && optionArrayCopy.get(position).getImageUrl().length() > 0) {
        final Bitmap bmp = loader.loadImageBitmap(optionArray.get(position).getImageUrl(), resDir);
        vHolderMultiple.iv.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        if (bmp != null) {
            vHolderMultiple.iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    } else
        vHolderMultiple.iv.setImageBitmap(null);
```

Comment: how about this tutorial: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html

Answer (score 0):

Same issue is occurred with checkbox with listview.

Use CheckedTextView UI component

OR

You need to code that manually. Add the setonclicklistner to Textview & pass the checkbox object to it. On net lots of code sample available.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please post a example link for this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a OnClickListener to the TextView and check/uncheck the CheckBox inside it. Something like this:

```
vHolderMultiple.tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){

        if(vHolderMultiple.cb.isChecked())
            vHolderMultiple.cb.setChecked(false);
        else
            vHolderMultiple.cb.setChecked(true);
    }
});
```

Note that you must declare cd as final in order to be able to change its state from an OnClick method.

Comment: I had more than one option. This doesn't suits for my app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using ListView to show some texts with image and checkbox.

It's better to use a CheckedTextView instead, which is a TextView combined with a CheckBox. And use TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() to replace the ImageView.

Then you can enable multiple choice mode by ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE). And ListView will helps to manage the check state of each row.